# How can I encrypt with a matrix key using ECB mode?

Tags: ecb

Given this plaintext: 101010101010, and the block is 3, with a IV = 000 and the key as
k = |1 2 3|
|2 1 3|
What are the required steps to get the same result like these in ECB mode:
c1 = Ek(m1) = 011, c2 = Ek(m2) = 100, c3 = Ek(m3) = 011 et c4 = Ek(m4) = 100.
c = c1||c1||c1||c1 = 011100011100.

**Note:**
*It is not a homework/ test, I just making some preparation.*

Full exercice and its solution are bellow:
[image]

[image]

Comment: the concept "matrix key" is nonstandard and unclear. also, smells like homework / test question, which is off topic

Comment: @kodlu This is not a homework, this is preparation and it happen I am trying to solve some exercices.

Comment: ok, seems to be some Mini AES resembling block cipher. Still your terminology is meaningless without further info, you should translate the details from french. What is the alphabet? Etc. etc.

Comment: The underlying 'block cipher' you are expected to use is simply a permutation of three elements, defined by the key $k$. That is $k$ defines a permutation $\pi$ such that $\pi(1) = 2$, $\pi(2) = 1$, and $\pi(3) = 3$. Its domain and co-domain are thus bit strings of length three.